# Oracle fpull out duplicate data between two table

Tags: sql, oracle

Table **`emp`** :

| UserId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ken |
| 3 | John |
| 5 | Gary |
| 7 | May |
| 9 | Simon |

Table **`role`** :

| UserId | Role |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Staff |
| 3 | Staff |
| 3 | Hr |
| 5 | Hr |
| 7 | Hr |
| 7 | Staff |
| 9 | Hr |

When the UserId appear two times in Table Role means the person are having two roles. Then extract the Name inthe Table EMP and below is my expected result. How ca I do it？

Expected result :

| Name |
| --- |
| John |
| May |

Here is the code I currently have. I can only selected from Table Role instead of the name from EMP.

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(*) AS Duplicate
  FROM Role
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: Join this result with the `emp` table. What is the issue with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet there are another options ;

by using `IN` operator :

```
SELECT Name
  FROM emp e
 WHERE e.UserId IN ( SELECT UserId FROM role GROUP BY UserId HAVING COUNT(*)>1 )
```

by using `EXISTS`(even without need of a GROUP BY clause) :

```
SELECT Name
  FROM emp e
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM role WHERE UserId = e.UserId HAVING COUNT(*)>1 )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c6e9b8aefc9302321743e038f3fd011c)</kbd>

Comment: `SELECT *` may result in a syntax error in the second query. I always use `SELECT NULL` with `EXISTS` for that reason. Others use `SELECT 1` or still something different.

Comment: Yes, mostly they(frequently me) prefer using a constant such as `1`, thanks for pointing out @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH
    emp AS
        (
            SELECT 1 "USER_ID", 'Ken' "U_NAME" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 "USER_ID", 'John' "U_NAME" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 "USER_ID", 'Gary' "U_NAME" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 7 "USER_ID", 'May' "U_NAME" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 9 "USER_ID", 'Simon' "U_NAME" FROM DUAL 
        ),
    role AS
        (
            SELECT 1 "USER_ID", 'Staff' "ROLE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 "USER_ID", 'Staff' "ROLE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 "USER_ID", 'Hr' "ROLE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 "USER_ID", 'Hr' "ROLE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 7 "USER_ID", 'Hr' "ROLE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 7 "USER_ID", 'Staff' "ROLE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 9 "USER_ID", 'Hr' "ROLE" FROM DUAL
        )   
        
SELECT 
    e.U_NAME "NAME"
FROM emp e
INNER JOIN role r ON (r.USER_ID = e.USER_ID)
GROUP BY e.U_NAME
HAVING Count(*) > 1
--  
--  R e s u l t
--
--  NAME
--  -----
--  John  
--  May
```